# Android: Fit in three large imageviews

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I have an imageview that displays an image that covers about half the screen. This is the class:

```
public class DialButton2 extends ImageView{

    public DialButton2(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setImageResource(R.drawable.dialpad);
    }

    public DialButton2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setImageResource(R.drawable.dialpad);
    }

}
```

My problem is how to fit THREE of these in on the screen. If I add one of these in using xml, I can use wrap_content and it will wrap content, I can use fill_parent and it will scale up and fill parent, but if I need to fit in three in a row, how should I force xml to scale them and fit them all in as a group of three? My current code doesnt work, it puts two in a row in and leaves out the third (because it occupies space outside of the screen):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<com.com.com.DialButton2
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />
<com.com.com.DialButton2
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />
<com.com.com.DialButton2
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<com.com.com.DialButton2
android:id="@+id/button3"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
```

Use this for all 3 views

Answer (score 1):

You can use [layout weights](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) (equal ones for all 3 subviews) while setting their layout widths to 0px. This will make them each take up proportional measures to combine to fill the available space.

Comment: Will this make them scale to fit as three in a row on ANY screen size/phone? It this a best practice?

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt seem to be working. Any other ideas or hints?

Comment: Yes, this is the standard way to say "I want each view in this LinearLayout to take up this proportion of the overall layout." What exactly isn't working? Have you tried this with (non-custom) views (say, a textview)? Did you set layout_width for each child view to 0px, and set each layout_weight to 1?  You also may want to play with the `adjustViewBounds` property.